# Determine if a UITableViewCell of a UICollectionView contained in a UITableView is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableView` which contains a `UICollectionView` and I need to determine if the `UITableViewCell` of the `UICollectionView` are visible or not.

I tried to use these methods :
`indexPathsForVisibleItems` of `UICollectionView` objects, but it returns to me an array with all my `UICollectionViewCells` (the count on the array returns to me 799 when only 30 cells are visible), and I get the same result when I used the method `visibleCells` of `UICollectionView` objects which returns to me the same array.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few ways to define visible.  Perhaps if the edge of a cell is visible, then the cell may itself be considered as visible.  If you wish to check it the entire cell is visible, you may try something like checking that the cell's frame is entirely contained within the UICollectionView's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough context for us to have a good guess, however, I can demonstrate a case where `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableView` reports the correct number of visible items using `-indexPathsForVisibleItems`:

1. Download the [`AFTabledCollectionView` project](https://github.com/AshFurrow/AFTabledCollectionView) from Github.
2. Open the project in Xcode and go to `AFViewController.m`.
3. Paste the following somewhere in the implementation:

   ```
   - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       NSArray *items = [collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
       NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)items.count);
   }
   ```
4. Run the project in the simulator and tap on an item in any `UICollectionView`. You will see in the console that the correct number of visible items for the collection view is being displayed.